# Lego Technic 60C01 Clutch Gear Bore size

Tags: technic, gears, size

I was wondering what the bore size is off the 60C01 clutch gear as I was unable to find it anywhere. Also, what is the pitch of such gear?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had to buy one to check the specs. The Bore size is just under 4 mm (~3.5 mm) in diameter. Without the teeth of the clutch it is just under 5 mm.

Answer (score 3):

Outer (hub): 6.8 mm/.268 in./ 17/64 in.
Inner (shaft): 4.9 mm/ .193 in./ 25/128 in.
Teeth (key): 3.32 mm/ .1305 in./ 17/128 in.

-These are close/approximate, not exact due to the tolerances and/or wear. I measured 4 different gears with a digital caliper and the measurements were all within .10 mm of the listed measurements. The measurements even varied slightly within a single gear depending on side and orientation.

Also, I think you can find the answer to your second question about pitch here: "[What is the "Module" of a LEGO gear?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6550/what-is-the-module-of-a-lego-gear)"